# How to get a value from a string value that is coming in a payload,

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule-esb

I am getting a payload with some keys that are having values for example

```
1. mulesoft[04444]
2. muleworld[88990]
```

now I want to extract content that is enclosed in square brackets here.

let's take an actual problem, here incoming payload

```
{
    "message": "Hello world[009]",
    "sender" : "myself[001]",
    "to": "friend[0089]"
}
```

here I want to create a Mulesoft function inside data weave code that I can use to extract value that is enclosed in the square brackets

Please write a DWL code fro this.

Comment: What have you done so far - plz show us your code.

Comment: I had written this script in transform message.
```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Strings
output application/json
fun extract(key)= substringBefore((substringAfter(key, "[")),"]")
---
{
    value: extract(payload.message)
}

```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this issue today in one of the API, so I thought that I should share this with others too.
I had written DWL code for its as below

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Strings
output application/json
fun extract(key)= substringBefore((substringAfter(key, "[")),"]")
---
{
    value: extract(payload.message)
}
```

it gave me desired o/p

```
{
  "value": "009"
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the contents in the [] would constitute the last part of a given text, you could also try this:

```
((payload.message splitBy("["))[1]) replace ("]") with ""
```